# Vectorizing and De-vectorizing parts of matrices

Tags: matlab, indexing, vectorization

I'm having real trouble understanding where the error in this code is:

I have a stack of matrices, and I want to take the upper triangular part of each, put that into a vector, do something with it, and map the result back. Here's the code:

```
%%
n=10;
m=3;

% generate a random 'stack of matrices'
bar=randn(n,n,m);

% index the upper triangular part
inds=triu(true(n,n));

% linearize
bar_lin=permute(bar,[3 1 2]);
bar_lin=bar_lin(:,inds);

% de-linearize
foo=zeros(size(bar,3),n,n);
foo(:,inds)=bar_lin;
foo=permute(foo,[2 3 1]);

% why is this not == 0 ??
sum(foo(:)-bar(:))
```

I just cannot understand why this doesn't work! Thanks!

Comment: Added matlab tag - hope this helps finding the correct audience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last line of code will not return `0`. That is because the `bar` variable stores both the upper as well as lower triangular parts of the matrix, whereas foo only stores the upper triangular part. You are basically subtracting something like this

```
bar = [1 2 3;
       4 5 6;
       7 8 9]
foo = [1 2 3;
       0 5 6;
       0 0 9]
foo - bar = [ 0  0  0;
             -4  0  0;
             -7 -8  0]
% Thus it will not be 0 for this case
% even sum(foo(:) - bar(:)) will not be 0
```

Only if the lower part (the part that is not in foo) sums to 0 will you get the output as 0 (but that will be rare in case of random numbers)

Comment: jup, thanks. I just saw that. Embarrassing ... basically, forgot to add `bar(repmat(not(inds),[1 1 m]))=0;`.